# Interpret multiple 'command' style arguments

Tags: java, parsing, command-line, jcommander

JCommander has a nice feature that it refers to as [commands](http://jcommander.org/#Complex). The example they give looks like this:

```
git commit --amend -m "Bug fix"
```

Is it possible to configure JCommander (or any other command line parser), to accept multiple commands? For example:

```
mycommand drawCircle -colour "red" -radius 5 drawCircle -colour "blue" -radius 8
```

This is what I've tried.

CommandDrawCircle.java

```
package omniplot.commandline;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameters;

@Parameters(separators = "=", commandDescription = "Record changes to the repository")
public class CommandDrawCircle {

    @Parameter(names = {"--colour", "-c"})
    private String colour;

    @Parameter(names = {"--radius", "-r"})
    private int radius;
}
```

CommandMain.java

```
package omniplot.commandline;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommandMain {

    @Parameter(names = "draw", description = "Information about what to draw")
    private List<CommandDrawCircle> drawCommands = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    CommandMain cm = new CommandMain();
    JCommander jc = new JCommander(cm);

    CommandDrawCircle draw = new CommandDrawCircle();
    jc.addCommand("drawCircle", draw);
    String cmd = jc.getParsedCommand();
```

That last line is where I am stuck. It only returns a single value, not a list of commands. Is there any way of having multiple commands?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JCommander, but the documentation has a method, `getCommands()` that returns a `Map<String, JCommander>`. Perhaps that is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Jonny, that looks promising however it returns the value I added in the 2nd last line